# Available online tftp servers

Tags: wireshark, sniffer, tftp

Are there any TFTP servers which I can contact in order to examine traffic using Wireshark or do I need to start my own TFTP server on localhost

Answer (score 0):

To examine TFTP traffic, you need to be **connected on a network where there is TFTP traffic**. So, if you sniff the traffic when sending files to a distant TFTP servers, you'll see :

- What the **TFTP server** sends to you
- What your **TFTP client** (your PC) sends to the TFTP server

*So, what you need to do is :*

1. Download a TFTP Client
2. Run wireshark and listen to traffic
3. Send files to a distant TFTP Server opened to everyone

### **Otherwise**,

You can also run a **TFTP server on your own computer**, there are severals existing software **but you'll also need a TFTP client**.

- You may use as example for the server any TFTP, I use for my works [Pumpkin](http://kin.klever.net/pumpkin#.XOFI-sgzaUk)
- And any client, for example [TFTP Client for Windows](http://www.tftp-server.com/tftp-client.html)

I also suggest you to consult the [RFC 1350 protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1350) documentation about TFTP.

Answer (score 0):

Download Serva which includes a TFTP Server and Client.
You can even transfer files within the same PC targeting a loopback address.
(localhost or 127.0.0.1).